# NoSuchMethodError in MaxentTagger

Tags: classpath, stanford-nlp, nosuchmethoderror

I am using stanford Parser in my code. I have added all the relevent libraries in the project. When I run my code on console it works perfectly fine. But after creating a 'runnable jar' of the source with an option "Copy required libraries into a subfolder next to the generated JAR" and run the same on commmand promt it throws an error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:*
>   edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor.(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(MaxentTagger.java:852)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(MaxentTagger.java:837)
>           at I have provided all the required libraries in classpath. Also the method tokenizeText is present in the MaxentTagger. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

This almost certainly means that you have combined incompatible releases of the parser and tagger. E.g., perhaps the version of the tagger being inserted into the jar file is different to the one picked up when you run the code on the command-line.  What versions of the parser and tagger are you using?  From the line numbers in the stacktrace, it appears not to be the latest version.

Comment: I am using maxent-2.5.2 and stanford-parser-2010-08-20, and they should be compatible as they are working perfectly fine on console. Also i have copied the same jars in library of runnable jar.

Comment: ?? "maxent-2.5.2" isn't a version number of our POS tagger, but the stacktrace you show is clearly from the stanford pos tagger. However, this info does make clearer the problem: Between the 2010 and 2011 releases of our tools, incompatible changes were made to the API of DocumentPreprocessor. In particular, a constructor which takes a Reader argument was added. Your (fairly) current version of the tagger is calling that constructor, but the DocumentPreprocessor class in your 2010 version of the parser jar does not have it. In general, you need to use compatible parser and tagger releases.